# Where do you buy Dogecoin from?

Tags: currencies, dogecoin

Interested in putting 10$ on a few random coins of the more popular variety, just for the fun of it.

Never had any connection to crypto, so absolutely no idea how this works.

Where can I go, create an account and grab some Dogecoin, without getting scammed or landing on dubious/malicious websites/apps ?

I have zero interest in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list of Doge exchanges: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/markets/

Google some of them and add "credit card" to your query.

It may involve buying BTC and selling your BTC for Dogecoin on the same website.